# Qué otra biblioteca reemplaza a Conio?

Tags: c++

Entiendo que ésta biblioteca debe evitarse por ser no standart.
Qué otra usamos en su lugar que tenga funciones equivalentes?

Comment: *Estandar*, **ninguna**. C++ no tiene el concepto de `pantalla`, `terminal`, ni nada parecido.

Comment: Otra cosa ... `Entiendo que ésta biblioteca debe evitarse por ser no standart ...` ¿ De donde te sacas eso ? Si no se pudieran usar cosas fuera del estandar, bien poco podrías hacer. Es perfectamente usable, siendo conscientes de que solo funcionará en ciertas plataformas.

Comment: Agradezco mucho tu aporte, lo he leído mas de una vez y trato de aprender a programar lo mejor posible ( intuyo que corregir errores luego se hace difícil).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Qué otra biblioteca reemplaza a Conio?

Si te ciñes al estándar de C++, para la entrada/salida utilizas `cin` y `cout`. Fíjate que esas clases no dicen nada de *consola*, *terminal*, *pantalla*, *teclado* o similar. De hecho no tendría sentido que así fuese porque **no están pensadas para trabajar específicamente con estos dispositivos**.

`cin` y `cout` atacan a la entrada estándar y la salida estándar respectivamente... y no, la entrada estándar **no tiene** por qué ser necesariamente la consola ni la entrada estándar el teclado. La entrada estándar puede ser cualquier fuente de datos (teclado, archivo, un socket, ...) mientras que la salida estándar podría ser cualquier tipo de consumidor (consola, impresora, archivo, socket, ...).

Si te fijas, por ejemplo, en los dispositivos que he mencionado en la salida estándar son bastante variopintos, cada uno con sus propias características:

**Consola**

- Admite acceso aleatorio.
- Normalmente normalizada a 80 caracteres por línea

**Impresora**

- No admite acceso aleatorio
- Longitud de línea dependiente de la configuración de la impresora

**Archivo**

- Admite acceso aleatorio
- No hay limitación en la longitud de la línea

**Socket**

- No admite acceso aleatorio
- No hay limitación en la longitud de la línea

Fíjate que no hay dos dispositivos iguales, luego el diseño de una interfaz capaz de comunicarse indistintamente con cualquiera estos dispositivos tiene que actuar teniendo en cuenta las diferentes restricciones:

- No admite acceso aleatorio. Esta limitación está clara.
- No hay límite en la longitud de la línea: Aunque pueda parecer extraño es así. Lo que sucede en este caso es que es la interfaz del propio dispositivo el que gestiona los datos para dividirlos en líneas diferentes si así procede.

Y todo esto para llegar a la conclusión de que no vas a encontrar, al menos de momento, una librería estándar que reemplace a `Conio`.

> Entiendo que ésta biblioteca debe evitarse por ser no standart

La biblioteca estándar no es más que un conjunto de funcionalidades que vienen por defecto al instalar cualquier compilador. Es un punto de partida común que permite que puedas programar los ejercicios de clase en tu casa en tu flamante Windows y después enseñárselos al profesor en un Linux instalado en un cascajo de equipo antediluviano.

Todos los lenguajes incluyen una biblioteca estándar. Esta biblioteca suele contener, al menos, una suerte de utilidades básicas de uso común (contenedores, gestión básica de la entrada / salida, acceso a archivos, ...).

Sin embargo, un lenguaje ni obliga a usar la biblioteca estándar ni limita la extensión de la misma. De hecho tu podrías crear tu propia versión de la bibliteca estándar o incluso pasar de ella y programar las diferentes utilidades según las vayas necesitando... ahora bien, en esas condiciones el coste de desarrollo se va a disparar.

Así pues, dado que no es algo que esté limitado, cualquiera es libre de crear y publicar librerías con utilidades. Así, hoy en día encuentras librerías para casi cualquier cosa:

- Librerías matemáticas: eigen, armadillo, mtl4, ...
- Librerías graficas: wxwidget, gtk+, ...
- Popurrí: Qt, boost, ...
- Librerías de audio, de video, criptografía, concurrencia, ...

Cuando se comenta acerca de que la conveniencia de evitar el uso de *Conio* se refieren sobretodo durante la fase de aprendizaje. Piensa que C++ es uno de los lenguajes más complicados de dominar. No en vano solo el estándar, es decir, las reglas básicas del lenguaje, tiene más de 1000 páginas.

En este caso *Conio* tiene como principal inconveniente que no es portable, por lo que no va a estar disponible en todos los sistemas operativos ni todos los compiladores. Tener que estar pendiente de este tipo de detalles (que básicamente hacen que tu programa deje de compilar así de repente) cuando estás aprendiendo C++ no es plato de buen gusto y de ahí que se desaconseje el uso de librerías no estándar.

Comment: Muy agradecido, realmente me está costando aprender C++ y apenas comienzo. Valoro mucho tu tiempo y el conocimiento que compartes. Gracias totales.