# No logro calcular el porcentaje y total de ventas

Tags: c++

El ejercicio es el siguiente

Una zapatería tiene 4 vendedores:

1. Florencia.
2. Victoria.
3. Nicolas.
4. Juan.

Tiene una oferta de 3 tipos de zapatillas:

1. Nike.
2. Adidas.
3. Reebok.

Cada vez que se realiza una venta se emite una factura:

- Numero de factura (0 para finalizar).
- Numero de empleado (1 a 4).
- Numero de Zapatilla (1 a 3).
- Importe de la venta.

A fin de mes se procesan las ventas y se pide imprimir:

1. venta totales de pesos de cada empleado.
2. porcentaje que vendió cada empleado sobre el total.
3. para cada empleado el nombre de la zapatilla que mas vendió.

NOTA: Los puntos A y B deben imprimirse ordenados de mayor a menor por ventas
Realizar una funcion de orden.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main (void)
{
   char nomven [4][10]={"Florencia","Victoria","Nicolas","Juan"},nomzap [4][7]={"Nike","Adidas","Rebook"};
   float ventas [4][4]={{0}},venemp[4]={0},poremp[4],maxemp[4],importe,total=0;
   int numfac,numemp,numzap,i,j,k=1,cota=3,aux,auxsuc[0,1,2,3];
   clrscr();
   printf("Numero de Factura : ");
   scanf("%d",&numfac);
   while(numfac!=0)
{
  do{
     printf("Numero de Empleado  (1 a 4) : ");
     scanf("%d",&numemp);
     }
  while(numemp>4||numemp<1);
  do{
       printf("Numero de Zapatilla  (1 a 3) : ");
       scanf("%d",&numzap);
      }
    while(numzap>4||numzap<1);
    printf("Importe de la Venta  :");
    scanf("%f",&importe);
     ventas[numemp-1][numzap-1]=ventas[numemp-1][numzap-1]+importe;
     printf("Numero de Factura : ");
     scanf("%d",&numfac);
         }
  for(i=0;i<4;i++)
  for(j=0;j<4;j++)
  venemp[i]=ventas[i][j];
  for(i=0;i<4;i++)total=total+venemp[i];
  for(j=0;j<4;j++)poremp[j]=venemp[j]/total*100;
  while(k!=0){
                k=0;
                for(i=0;i<cota-1;i++){
                                      if(auxsuc[i+1]>auxsuc[i]){
                                                                aux=auxsuc[i];
                                                                auxsuc[i]=auxsuc[i+1];
                                                                auxsuc[i+1]=aux;
                                                                k=i;
                                                                }
                                        } 
        cota=k;
                }
         for(i=0;i<4;i++){
                          maxemp[i]=ventas[i][0];
                          for(j=1;j<4;j++){
                        if(ventas[i][j]>maxemp[i])maxemp[i]=ventas[i][j];
                                         }
                        }
    orden(auxsuc,vensuc);
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    printf("Empleado: %s ventas:$ %.2f porcentaje: %.2f %% \n",nomemp[auxsuc[i]],venemp[auxsuc[i]],poremp[auxsuc[i]]);
    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
                     printf("Empleado:%s \n",nomemp[i]);
                     printf("La Zapatilla mas vendida fue:\n");
                     for(j=0;j<4;j++){
                                      if(maxsemp[i]==ventas[i][j])printf("%s \n",nomzap[j]);
                                      }
                      }
  getch();
  }
  void orden(int auxsuc[4],float vensemp[4])
  {
   int aux,k=1,cota=3,i;
   while(k!=0){
              k=0;
              for(i=0;i<cota;i++){
                                  if(venemp[auxsuc[i+1]]>=venemp[auxsuc[i]]){
                                                                             aux=auxsuc[i+1];
                                                                             auxsuc[i+1]=auxsuc[i];
                                                                             auxsuc[i]=aux;
                                                                             k=i;
                                                                              }
                                  }
               cota=k;
              }
  return;
}
```

Logro correr con éxito el programa pero en la pantalla luego de cargar los datos se muestra que en la primer fila no me esta calculando el porcentaje de las ventas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor edita y coloca un título un tanto mas objetivo y descriptivo del problema presentado, ya que colocar nivel básico no explica mucho del problema presentado

Comment: @Aprendiz estoy detallando el error en el posteo ya que poner "Logro correr con exito el programa pero en la pantalla luego de cargar los datos se muestra que en la primer fila no me esta calculando el porcentaje de las ventas." Es muy extenso, te pido que si entras al posteo y ves todo lo que escribi solo para comentar eso te ahorres los comentarios. Ya que lo pedi de la mejor forma posible

Comment: Nadie da una mano aca para mejorar y crecer todos critican y se burlan que triste esta pagina

Comment: Hola, tienes varias preguntas sobre diferentes aspectos del mismo programa. Es bueno ver que has ido progresando en el mismo, pero a la vez van quedando tu preguntas algo abandonadas ya que se te ha sugerido que des más detalles en las mismas. Incluso una de tus preguntas ha puesta en espera por no estar claro lo que se pregunta. Aqui trataremos en lo posible de ayudarte, pero debes dejarte ayudar. Nuestros comentarios no son para criticarte sino para indicarte lo que hace falta aportar para entender tus preguntas y darte una respuesta. Espero no lo tomes a mal. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Hola, muchas gracias por participar en mi posteo. Volviendo a tu comentario, si he creado varios posteos sobre el mismo programa y modificando el mismo con errores minimos que he encontrado ya sea de tipear de mas un ; { } o lo que fuere. Al ser un ingresante en esto de sistemas no logro ser mas descriptivo de lo que estoy siendo por la falta de experiencia que tengo. Por eso me remonto a este sitio donde hay profesionales donde puedan darme una mano.

Comment: Trataré de darte una respuesta a esta pregunta, si nadie lo ha hecho para cuando pueda sentarme frente a mi ordenador. Mi zona horaria actual me lo impide en este momento, pero en cuanto pueda lo haré. Te marco en favorita y seguro te doy una mano. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Actualizado con cambios, sigue sin calcular porcentajes ni ventas

Comment: Te han dado una excelente respuesta, creo que con eso tienes bastante para terminar el proyecto. Te recomiendo que si la respuesta es la que esperabas la marques como válida, de esa forma estarías indicando tu gratitud y de paso obtienes reputación. En cuanto a las demás preguntas que formulaste en el sitio, te sugiero que si no son relevantes y no aportan nada ya al problema, las elimines, de esa forma haces un poco de limpieza y no te sancionan automáticamente por dejar la casa sucia. ;) Saludos

Answer (score 2):

```
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
for(j=0;j<4;j++)
venemp[i]=ventas[i][j];
```

Las ventas del empleado (supongo que eso es lo que es `venemp`) siempre obtienen el valor de la última venta realizada, ya que no estás sumando si no asignando. Como el valor de ventas está mal, el porcentaje obviamente saldrá mal. Seguramente querías hacer esto:

```
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
for(j=0;j<4;j++)
venemp[i]+=ventas[i][j];
//       ^^ <--- Sumar la venta 'j' del empleado 'i' en venemp.
```

Pero ese es el menor de tus problemas. Tu código es un desastre:

- Etiquetas la pregunta como [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) cuando nada de tu código se parece a dicho lenguaje ¿No estarás usando [c](/questions/tagged/c) en realidad?
- Las cabeceras `<stdio.h>` y `<conio.h>` son de C, no de C++. Si necesitas usarlas (que no es el caso) deberías usar la versión adaptada a C++: `<cstdio>`. En cuanto a [`<conio.h>`, no tiene versión C++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/284545/2742).
- La función `main` **debe tener `int` como tipo de retorno**.
- En C++ las funciones que no reciben parámetros se dejan con el listado de parámetros vacío, no con `void`.
- Las variables deberían tener nombres autoexplicativos, los nombres de variables de una sola letra son confusos, las abreviaciones son propensas a malinterpretaciones y los nombres genéricos como `aux` y sus secuelas no aportan ninguna información a su misión ni razón de existir.
- En C++ no se suele trabajar con formaciones de caracteres, usa mejor `std::string`.
- En C++ se usa `std::cin` para lectura de datos y `std::cout` para escribir en consola, `printf` y `scanf` son funciones de C.
- Las zapatillas van de uno a tres, pero en el `do`-`while` compruebas que vayan de uno a cuatro.
- Apretujar el código no hará que mole más, al contrario: hará que sea más difícil de leer, de comprender y de depurar, ya estás sufriendo las consecuencias.

  - Además, no tiene sentido que lo apretujes cuando al final indentas algunas líneas hasta [Quintanilla de Arriba](https://www.google.es/maps/place/47360+Quintanilla+de+Arriba).

#### Propuesta.

Si corriges todos los problemas mencionados en los puntos anteriores y usas C++ como es debido, tu código podría parecerse a:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

struct Factura
{
    int id{};
    int id_empleado{};
    int id_zapatilla{};
    float importe{};
};

std::istream &operator >>(std::istream &i, Factura &f)
{
    std::cout << "Nº factura: ";
    std::cin >> f.id;

    if (f.id)
    {
        do
        {
            std::cout << "Nº empleado: ";
            std::cin >> f.id_empleado;
        } while (f.id_empleado < 1 || f.id_empleado > 4);

        do
        {
            std::cout << "Nº zapatilla: ";
            std::cin >> f.id_zapatilla;
        } while (f.id_zapatilla< 1 || f.id_zapatilla > 3);

        std::cout << "Importe de la venta: ";
        std::cin >> f.importe;
    }

    return i;
}

std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const Factura &f)
{
    return (o << "Factura " << f.id << '\n'
        << "\tEmpleado " << f.id_empleado << '\n'
        << "\tZapatilla " << f.id_zapatilla << '\n'
        << "\tImporte " << f.importe << '\n');
}

int main()
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    Factura factura[4]{};

    for (auto &f : factura)
        std::cin >> f;

    for (const auto &f : factura)
        std::cout << f << '\n';

    auto total_ventas = std::accumulate(begin(factura),
                    end(factura),
                    0.f,
                    [](auto a, auto &b)
                    {
                        return a + b.importe;
                    });

    std::cout << "Total ventas: " << total_ventas << '\n';

    for (auto empleado : { 1, 2, 3, 4})
    {
        auto total_empleado = std::accumulate(begin(factura),
                            end(factura),
                            0.f,
                            [&empleado](auto a, auto &b)
                            {
                                return a + (b.id_empleado == empleado ? b.importe : 0.f);
                            });

        std::cout << "Ventas de " << empleado << " = " << total_empleado
            << '(' << (100.f * total_empleado / total_ventas) << "% del total\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVRNj5swED3DrxilagIt3SabnAhJT63US09VD92sVg6YrCWwETGt1Cx/rMf@sXRsY76SXW1IjJkZZt57M05cFB8OcXw@v2E8zqqEQsTEUZaU5Fu3s/EqpyWLt66LviqW8IXEsiqJe3IdxiWw5FSv7faB5kVGSSL6tj@kIJJlGdHGNBMEzXkhSkmVBb@YOglDZorDVBS0JFKUsN16Qw8LbHmYpr6CoP2xqCREEUy@/fsLqQkIYbK2bsYxFaQ3LMFaDkvBU3vfdTCBkwhc1OZKLkvHJHMu0rV8lbeG348soyZ564EIFvD0NAyHLax8heXF6q1wz5ZvIy7rt65@/daIAJYGwLDsV9MXwM5j0C/KpS0@qm3i0FFjkpKi4hwYNrPppbjoZRR5I08AseBHOe5ok8wTGpB1TtST4qDusx2fISTl38nPVtM2pKf9KPZny78L7jQZR1sxbGzz2IT5mq2a8Zww7mns1ZHxA2iee3pgfD0wUa7nz1JqBvVuda@OAZ4MVMkjlRSoBITW7Y@1b0ONei@80DQ1tYjVmzpcCkmyB93dI2wMOBLHVV5lRFJPQ/dsukBNnuMg@LFpfpM2u7t7A5wEDZ69bxwnc7NNJfAe9r3hUZ9az@FwDL8rgGb8jqHRf4C5R6hTre16CCdYBHAbwDKAVd2c8x7zNvKV3K@y7/NHBaY26XNSdGIM5PD2g4ndbDoenzqtkBNW89c2Q33t8P4w4iTNxPZPwQSp9mS0LpVOaenNlM9bzLEIvBur9HEgvq/zvcUymbHv@GT4PzDHk3E@L1xz3TbrEn/qWul16f4H)</kbd>.